# Creating a Slide Show with Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, slideshow

I am very new to web development and am trying to create a slide show using JavaScript and HTML. The problem I keep running into is that when I FIRST load my page all the slide show text overlaps after that the slideshow runs as expected. 
[image]

```js
var current = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

setInterval(function() {
    
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;  
      
  }
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;     
   
}, 2500);
```

```css
.logo{
    width:100px;
    margin-left: 850px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    vertical-align:top;        
}


.show { 
  position: absolute;width:500px; height:200px; left:50%; top:50%; margin-top: -140px;margin-left: -250px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.descrip { 
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  position: absolute;width:500px; left:50%; top:50%; margin-top: 100px;margin-left: -250px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}



h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Tourism Slide Show</title>
    <link href = "travelPics.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="travelSlideShow.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body >
        <h1>Uncle Phil's Tourism</h1>
        <img src ='images/logo.jpg' class = "logo" alt = "logo">
     
        <div class = "slide" >
<img src="images/athens.jpg" alt="Athens" class="show" >
        <h2 class = "descrip">
        Acropolis of Athens in Athens Greece <br>
        The ruins of a 5th-century B.C temple.     
        </h2>
            </div>
            
           <div class = "slide">
<img src="images/burjkhalifa.jpg" alt="Burj Khalifa" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip">The tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m<br>Located in Dubai, United Arab Emirates</h2>
        </div>
              
        <div class = "slide">
<img src="images/cappadocia.jpg" alt="Cappadocia" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip">
        Located in central Turkey, is known for the Bronze Age homes carved into valley walls
        </h2>
               
               </div> 
        
        <div class = "slide">
<img src ="images/florence.jpg" alt ="Florence" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip">
       The  Cathedral of Santa Maria del Fiore and Piazza Duomo <br>
            Contains  art and architecture by the greatest artists of the Italian Renaissance -- Ghiberti, Brunelleschi, Donatello, Giotto, and Michelangelo. 
        </h2>
            </div>
        
        <div class = "slide">
<img src = "images/lighthouse.jpg" alt ="Lighthouse" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip"> Light house </h2>
            </div>
        
        <div class = "slide">
            
<img src = "images/louvre.jpg" alt = "Louvre" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip"> Louvre</h2>
            </div>
            
        <div class = "slide">
<img src = "images/victoriafalls.jpg" alt = "Victoria Falls" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip">Victoria falls </h2>
            
            </div>
        
        <div class = "slide"> 
<img src = "images/warmuseum.jpg" alt = "Canadian War Museum" class="show">
        <h2 class = "descrip"> War Museum</h2>
        </div>
        
        
        </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to wait until the page loads before running your code. Wrap your code with `window.onload = function () { ... };`.

Comment: Should I wrap the entire HTML code, or simple the <body> section?

Comment: Just the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform the first js part into the following:

```
//And manually call update once or at initial loading
//E.g. in jquery: $(document).on("load", update);
update();

setInterval(update, 2500);

function update()
{
      for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = 0;  

      }
      slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
      current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
}
```

The reason for this is that setInterval will call the function after 2,5 seconds for the very first time. So you should manually call it initially.

Comment: In my HTML I added <body onload = "update()">  and added what you have mentioned above into my JavaScript. However now when I first open the page it shows the screen with all the text overlapped for just a split second before the slideshow begins is that simply part of the page loading? Or have I made an error?

Comment: No this is not an error. on load is fired when really EVERYTHING has finished. So until ALL elements are loaded the texts will overlap. You could set the opacity in your css of the container containing all the elements to 0, and then add a css opacity transition to it (css3generator.com). In your update() method you can then add `document.getElementById("container-id").style.opacity = 1;` at the beginning which will leave it invisible and then slowly fade it in after everything has loaded. By using opacity and not display:none you will avoid jumping content on load.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!